# java , Apache POI - How to read Excel (.xlsx format) ListBox selected values in Java using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to read excel listbox in java.I have following code.

```
XSSFSheet sheet;
    XSSFRow row;
    XSSFCell cell;
    XSSFSimpleShape objectData;
    try (InputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream("D:\\test.xlsx");
         XSSFWorkbook workbook = new  XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);){
        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        for(XSSFShape shape : sheet.getDrawingPatriarch().getShapes()){

        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

XSSFShape object get listBox, but i can't get selected items.

Is there any better and working code ?

Please refer this link to see how to add listbox. This will help better understand my question.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/add-a-list-box-or-combo-box-to-a-worksheet-HP010236681.aspx

Comment: As far as I am aware it is not yet possible with Apache POI.